# Should questions about the history of biology be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Should we allow questions that are directly related to the history of our understanding of biology, rather than the biology itself? Where do we draw the line on historical questions? I don't have an example question to hand, but I can see this being an issue in future.

Comment: Okay, for a concrete example: would asking why Mendel settled on peas for his cross-breeding experiments be on-topic?

Comment: @J.M. - I was also thinking about questions related to the history of our understanding of diseases, especially ones we still don't fully understand, e.g. AIDS.

Comment: Yeah, that's good too. (For the record, I support historical questions as being on topic.)

Comment: I think the Mendel example question is a *perfect* reason as to why they should be considered on topic =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that history of biology is important, it can show us development of this field of science so I would accept this kind of questions.