# Can I ask questions about the practice of biology?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Naturally, we expect on a site like this that biology itself is discussed. But what about related things that concern biologists?

What I do know is that:

- [Equipment recommendations are off-topic](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/can-you-ask-questions-about-equipment-recommendations), a good thing, I think.
- [The history of biology is on-topic](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/should-questions-about-the-history-of-biology-be-considered-on-topic), also a good thing.
- [Questions about teaching biology can be on-topic](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/questions-about-teaching-biology-off-limits), also a good thing.
- Questions tagged [protocol](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol), [image-processing](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), [protocol](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol), and [research-process](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process) all exist.

I think it would also be good if we could ask about specific things that would concern biologists of various kinds. For example, I have a specific question regarding insect preservation that would concern entomologists. I imagine other questions like lab procedures, cataloging formalities, and specimen acquisition would be very useful questions and attract practicing experts.

Are these questions allowed?

Comment: I couldn't wait and asked the question: [How to protect my mounted insect specimens from ... insects?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599)

Comment: Your question looks like it was fairly well received, so I guess you have your answer! Speaking of which, please remember to accept one of the answers to your question and click the arrow next to it, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer (and even others) if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: There are lots of question tagged with 'techniques'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about the practice of biology are absolutely on-topic. In fact, there's a tag [lab-techniques](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-techniques) dedicated to it, and possibly others for other non-lab biological practitioners as well. This site is of, by, and for biologists, and many good questions relate to the day-to-day of our work:

- [How long can I store extracted RNA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/973/how-long-can-i-store-extracted-rna)
- [How can I label cryotubes in a way that eliminates the problem of legible hand-writing?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/how-can-i-label-cryotubes-in-a-way-that-eliminates-the-problem-of-legible-hand-w)
- [Does the Petri dish lid orientation on workbench affect aseptic technique?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11011/does-the-petri-dish-lid-orientation-on-workbench-affect-aseptic-technique)
- [What is the best way to express two proteins in a mammalian cell?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/what-is-the-best-way-to-express-two-proteins-in-a-mammalian-cell)
- [Basic step by step methods for PCR & Gel electrophoresis class](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13432/basic-step-by-step-methods-for-pcr-gel-electrophoresis-class)

and many, many more. There are also a plethora of questions regarding how to do theoretical genetics, online database searching and analysis, phylogenetic classification, sample collection in "the real world" (i.e., outside the lab), and others. If it directly relates to a branch of biology, go for it!